# How to center vertically figcaption?

Tags: html

I'd like a figcaption to be next to a image in the middle of this image. How can i do this? I have tried like this:

```
<figure>
     <img src="Pic1" style="width:60%; height:auto; float:right" />
     <figcaption class="title" style="vertical-align:middle">xxx</figcaption>
</figure>
```

but the caption is still on the top of the image.

Comment: Vertical-align:middle doesn't also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```css
figure {
   display:table;
}
figure figcaption.title {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
figure img {
   display:table-cell;
   width:60%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <figcaption class="title">xxx</figcaption>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300"/>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your figure display as flex, and then use auto margins to center the caption.

```css
figure {
  display: flex;
}

figure figcaption {
  margin: auto 10px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    <figcaption>A random picture</figcaption>
</figure>
```